# SSH exitOnForwardFailure=yes doesn't work for local forwards (-L)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want to use the `ExitOnForwardFailure` ssh option, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ ssh -f -L 8080:localhost:22 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes root@server.com "sleep 60" ; sleep 3; ps xu|grep ssh
bind: Address already in use
halfgaar     780086  0.0  0.0  51432   728 ?        Ss   12:32   0:00 ssh -f -L 8080:localhost:22 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes root@server.com sleep 60
```

Also if I don't fork (`-f`), I just get a shell to the server:

```
halfgaar@<localmachine>: ~
$ ssh -L 8080:localhost:22 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes root@server.com
bind: Address already in use
Linux <remoteserver> 4.9.0-8-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3 (2019-02-02) i686

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri May 31 12:39:27 2019 from 84.22.107.110
root@<remoteserver>: ~
#
```

It does work properly when I try to make a *reverse* tunnel (`-R`).

Ubuntu 18.04, SSH 7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3.

Comment: Just to add that if you don't want a shell (tty) to be spawned, you can use -N

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's using ipv4 for one part, and ipv6 for another. When I use `-4`, I properly get:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8080                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Could not request local forwarding.
```

I also [filed a bug report](http://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3017), because it does seem like a bug.