# reverse ssh tunnel issues

Tags: linux, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to allow access to a remote network behind a 4g router.

Since 4g dows not allow to bind ports from the router to the internal network, I'm trying to setup a reserve tunnel.

But it's quite unstable. After a certain amount of time, the connection seems to be dropped ; the only trick I have found is to reboot the target of the tunnel (a VPS server).
This allows the tunnel to be accessible on a quite random basis.

From inside my remote network, on a PI computer with raspbian 10, I use the autossh command :

```
autossh -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -NR 0.0.0.0:8822:localhost:22 user@my-vps.ovh.net
```

When started, this tunnel allows me to connect to the PI through the VPS and the tunnel.

But as said before, after a random amount of time (several minutes / few hours), one end seems to be disconnected.

I'm trying to understand what's the problem here, I lack of forensics tools to get some details.

Also, I've tried localtunnel : Works, but after a random amount of time also, the connection crash with a message refering to "check your firewall settings"

I'm suspecting the 4g operator (free mobile / france) to be the cause of this.

Can I log some stuff to know more on the both ends ?

Thanks.

Edit:

As suggested, ran ssh with the following line :

```
ssh user@164.132.xxx.xxx -v -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes
```

After some time (undetermined), got the following result :

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 164.132.xxx.xxx port 22: Broken pipe
```

Comment: On the machine running autossh, perhaps you can run normal SSH for a while, and do `ssh -v`. Also, I would use `ExitOnForwardFailure`, but then do look at: https://serverfault.com/questions/969637/ssh-exitonforwardfailure-yes-doesnt-work-for-local-forwards-l

Comment: Finally got the result (cannot connect for a few days...)

packet_write_wait: Connection to 164.132.xxx.xxx port 22: Broken pipe

command used : ssh user@164.132.xxx.xxx -v -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes

Comment: Can you edit the question and put the information in it?